# Error al ejecutar un proyecto usando Maven

Tags: maven

Tengo el siguiente error, al ejecutar un proyecto. Uso JHipster, el cual lo tengo instalado, pienso ejecutar este proyecto, pero al ejecutar el Maven, (lo uso para que salga la dirección local, mas el puerto), pero ejecuto el comando `--mvnw--` y me sale este error

```
C:\Users\crist\Desktop\GAOH_CEET-develop\04. Pruebas\02. Jhipster\gaoh>mvnw
El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo C:\Users\crist\Desktop\GAOH_CEET-develop\04..
Found "C:\Users\crist\Desktop\GAOH_CEET-develop\04. Pruebas\02. Jhipster\gaoh\.mvn\wrapper\maven-wrapper.jar"
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.445 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-05-26T10:23:03-05:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No goals have been specified for this build. You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoGoalSpecifiedException

C:\Users\crist\Desktop\GAOH_CEET-develop\04. Pruebas\02. Jhipster\gaoh>
```

No he podido solucionarlo. Si alguien ha trabajado con Maven, y sabe como evitar este error y que al ejecutar ese comando salga limpio la ejecución, les agradecería.

Comment: Tienes un pom.xml en el proyecto? Todo indica que no

Comment: ¿Desde qué entorno ejecutas el proyecto? ¿Qué escribes exactamente para ejecutarlo? Luego, esos nombres de carpetas / archivos con puntos, yo lo evitaría a toda costa.

Comment: en la consola prueba con `mvn clean install`

Comment: @Alfabravo si el pom.xml si lo tengo